# INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger "Invalid column name 'cost'."

Tags: sql-server, triggers

[Image of error and SQL code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIxzF.png)

I am writing an INSTEAD OF UPDATE tigger for my yacht database and I am having trouble with the column name cost which is located in the yacht table. The error says that it is an invalid column name but I have checked that it is spelt correctly and I have refreshed my database. This is what it looks like. Would anybody be able to help me please?

Comment: Please don't kill kittens. Read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You need to use the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables in your trigger and consider that the trigger will fire once even when multiple rows are affected. Instead of `IF cost > 1200.00`, use `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE cost > 1200.00)`. The trigger `UPDATE` statement will update every row in the table because you are not joining to `inserted` to limit to only the updated rows.

Comment: I think you need to review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 particularly discussion of 'DML triggers use the deleted and inserted logical (conceptual) tables' need more help. Publish yacht table definition and trigger as text together with sample data and update statements. as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server triggers work a bit differently than perhaps in another database engines.

For insert, update and delete triggers, the actual table is already changed with the new values, while in INSTEAD OF trigger, nothing is changed yet.

SQL Server exposes the data being updated, inserted or deleted by two pseudo-tables, called `inserted` and `deleted` which trigger code can read and reason about.
Different triggers have access to different tables (simplified):

- insert trigger populates inserted table with all rows being inserted
- deleted trigger populates deleted table with all rows being deleted
- update trigger is the special one, it populates inserted table with the new data being inserted, and deleted table with the old data.
- instead of triggers populate same tables as the above

Another difference is that SQL Server works on the whole data amount at the same time, instead of row by row. This is a classic gotcha that many people mess up and think only one row is being processed by trigger code.

So, what about your specific problem.
IF (cost > 1200) makes no sense according to the above, because trigger doesn't have access to columns, but rather to tables.

What you want is something like:

```sql
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM inserted i
  WHERE cost > 1200
)
begin
   THROW 50001, N'cost too high', 1;
   -- rolls back transaction and returns
end

UPDATE t
   SET cost = i.cost * 1.1
   FROM yacht t
   INNER JOIN inserted i
     ON i.yachtID = t.yachtID;
```

Note that you have to change the update as well, and join together the inserted rows with your real table.

This is all explained better at [Microsoft trigger docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much I really appreciate

Comment: `rollback transaction` should never be used in a trigger, it causes spurious "transaction ended in the trigger" errors. Instead just do `THROW 50001, N'cost too high', 1;` which will roll back automatically while giving the correct error message.

Comment: @Charlieface good point, i was following OPs example. The way i understand it after reading some stuff, THROW does rollback and finishes whole batch but RAISERROR doesn't.